# How to retrieve OracleCommand parameters from ProfiledDbCommand

Tags: c#, casting, oraclecommand, miniprofiler

I started using the [StackExchange mini profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) and wanted to use it with oracle database.
But the exception is thrown when I run the query-

`Unable to cast object of type 'StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand' to type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand'`.

I create new connection:

```
this._oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString.Oracle);
this._dbConnection = new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(this._oracleConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);
```

Method in which I run the query:

```
private long InsertData(SomeModel model, long someId, DbConnection conn)
{
    OraDynamicParams insrtParams = this.GetSomeParams(model);
    insrtParams.Add("a_some_id", someId);
    insrtParams.Add("cur_OUT", dbType: OracleDbType.RefCursor, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
    dynamic res = conn.Query("SOME_CRUD.INSERT_PROC", insrtParams, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();

    //...
}
```

*Note:* 
*`OraDynamicParams` is simply a class that inherits from `SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters`.*

In following method the exception is thrown when try to cast to `OracleCommand`:

```
void SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters.AddParameters(IDbCommand command, SqlMapper.Identity identity)
{
    var oracmd = (OracleCommand)command; // exception!
    this.AddParameters(oracmd, identity);
}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. 
It appears that inside the `StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand` there is a property `InternalCommand` that is of type `OracleCommand`. From there you can retrieve all added parameters. 
After modifying the code, it looks something like this:

```
void SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters.AddParameters(IDbCommand command, SqlMapper.Identity identity)
{
     // Checks if profiler is used, if it is, then retrieve `InternalCommand` property
     dynamic oracmd = command is OracleCommand ? command : ((ProfiledDbCommand)command).InternalCommand;
     this.AddParameters((OracleCommand)oracmd, identity);
}
```